# Understand Scopes in ES6 modules and functions

Tags: javascript, scope, grid, ecmascript-6

I am trying to set up an ES6 environment with some libraries installed via nmp.
This all works as charm and now I try to make a drag-able dashboard working with the npm package [draggable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/draggable).

Setup looks like that:

```
<div id="container" data-module="Grid">
 <div class="ball green"></div>
 <div class="ball red"></div>
</div>
```

sadasd

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import Draggable from 'draggable';
import { forEach, find, filter, reduce } from 'lodash';

export default class Grid
{
  constructor($select) {

    this.grid = {
        options: [],
    };

    this.$container = document.getElementById('container');
    this.$element1 = document.getElementsByClassName('ball')[0];
    this.$element2 = document.getElementsByClassName('ball')[1];

    console.log(this.$element1);
    console.log(this.$element2);

    var options = {
        limit: this.$container,
        grid: 200,
        setCursor: true,
        onDragEnd: this.update
    };

    this.drag  = new Draggable(this.$element1, options);
    this.drag2 = new Draggable(this.$element2, options);

    this.upGrid(0, 0);
  }

  update(elem, x, y) {
    console.log($(elem));
    console.log(x+'/'+y);
    this.upGrid(x, y);
  }

  upGrid(x, y) {
    console.log(this.drag.get());
    this.grid.options.push(x+'/'+y);
    console.log(this.grid.options);
  }
}
```

The problem:
The function update is defined to be called by a draggable element at the end of a drag event. This works but the function has no access to the grid variable created in the constructor. And it also does not know about the function upGrid(). I guess it is because it somehow lives within the draggable-package.

Can someone please help me to understand why and how I can manage the scopes of these functions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This has nothing to do with ES6, modules or scope really, only with how `this` works.

Comment: Oh I was looking at it the wrong way, sorry. Thanks for putting my head in the right direction, the other post clarifies a lot.